# PhoneGap App: Where is the localstorage file?

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I know that localstorage is not secure if you use this from the browser. 
But if this would run in an app (iOS / Android), the data should be only available to that app - right?

So I would like to find out where the data are stored. Can I browse to a directory with these data?

Comment: did you get the answer to this?

Comment: Best answer is the one I marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If android then localstorage stored at /data/data/package_name/localstorage. You can view in DDMS in eclipse